# How to connect multiple devices on avr(atmega16/32) using UART?

Tags: avr, atmega16

atmega 32 has only one (TX/RX) .In case of connecting many devices working with UART  what should I do?....Arduino has something called   software serial
Is it available in atmega 32 or how to establish it?

Comment: Software serial (bit-banged RS-232) will not help you much when you're talking about *many* devices (it uses quite a bit of CPU capacity). You will probably need to look into bus structures and packetized transfer. (I2C could be an option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may also use a multiplexer if the peripheral devices do not need to operate at the same time. This is a bit trickier to use due to baud rate changes and such but I have used this approach in one of my projects where I had a serial printer and some other devices which interfaced with the MCU via UART.  The drivers for the said devices included calls to switch to the correct output on the multiplexer before communicating with the device.